# Adding default value to ASP TextBox with TextMode = Password

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I've found articles about this online, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my current HTML (with all the jumbled layout stuff taken out)

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"
OnAuthenticate="LoginUser_Authenticate">
    <LayoutTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Text="username" 
        CssClass="text-box login-text-box"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="text-box 
        login-text-box" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>

    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

Here is the server-side code I found online:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtPassword.Attributes.Add("value", "defaultpassword")
    }
```

I keep getting the message: "txtPassword does not exist in the current context".

I get that error for anything I change the, "txtPasssword", text to.

Comment: The ID of `TextBox` is "Password", not "txtPassword". Typo?

Comment: Like I said, I've tried "Password", it still tells me: "Password does not exist in this context". It's really wierd.

Comment: Probably because it is inside `<LayoutTemplate>` of `<asp:Login>` control, you might have to search for `TextBox` control inside `<asp:Login>`. Like so: `var myPasswordControl = (TextBox)LoginUser.FindControl("Password");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things.

First, you have to reference objects by their actual name.  As mikhairu pointed out, "txtPassword" is not an object name.  The TextBox object is "Password".

Second, and just as important, is that context matters.  Your page doesn't have a "Password" textbox on it.  The User control named "LoginUser" does.  So you need to do one of 2 things.  One option is to inherit from the Login control and add your code for setting the password, which is probably a bit beyond you and I'd consider it a bad idea anyway.  Another option is to do like the following:

```
LoginUser.Password.Attributes.Add("value", "defaultpassword");
```

However, I'm not entirely sure that will work.  More than likely you'll have to do:

```
TextBox txtPassword = (TextBox)LoginUser.FindControl("Password");
txtPassword.Attributes.Add("value", "defaultpassword");
```

Comment: You're assumption was correct.  You cannot reference it the former way.  To compound that issue, the `Login` control has a `Password` property.

Comment: Everyone had great answers, you went into a little more depth, which was the issue I had with all the answers I found on the web, so I think your answer will best help others who are having a similar issue that I was, so your answer gets the accept.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the control first since it's `NamingContainer` is the `Login`-control not the page:

```
var txtPassword = (TextBox)LoginUser.FindControl("PassWord");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your textbox lives inside the `LayoutTemplate` of your `Login` control, you must find it first.

Example:

```
TextBox txtPassword = (TextBox)LoginUser.FindControl("Password");
txtPassword.Attributes.Add("value", "defaultpassword");
```